# how to pass command line arguments to shell command in one-line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I ve a specific shell command , which runs on ubuntu terminal

So while running in a terminal, i'm invoking it like that :

```
mycommand
```

while running , under terminal , it starts to ask for some "prompts" (for configuration) which i should tape , like this :

[image]

and then , another time with another ask for "confirmation"

[image]

, and then for almost 10 other times for different config confirmations
where i'm taping diiferents responses

So my purpose is how to be able to do it in once , in only one-line command ??

i would try this :

```
mycommand "yes" "yes "no" ..... "yes"
```

But that's KO .

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: `printf "yes\nyes\nno\nyes\n" | mycommand`.

Comment: in more than one line, with a small script file to give answer to every specific prompts, you may use the command: expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know all the required inputs, you can create a file with the answers:

answers.in:

```
yes
yes
no
yes
```

and then

```
mycommand << answers.in
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* `mycommand` is reading from stdin and not from the tty, then you can get away with echoing responses into the command.  This is in fact one of the main reasons for the existence of the `yes` command:

```
yes | mycommand
```

will respond 'y' to all of the prompts.

```
yes foo | mycommand
```

will respond with 'foo' to all of the prompts.  If you want to answer 'yes' to some and 'no' to others, you can get creative and do things like:

```
yes yes | sed -e 3,5s/yes/no/ -e 10q | mycommand
```

(The above will respond "yes" to the first 2 prompts, then "no" to prompts 3 thru 5, and then "yes" to prompts 6 thru 10).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print` as '@William Pursell' wrote. I tend to use `echo` out of habit.

```
$ cat /tmp/x.sh
#!/bin/sh

read -p "alpha: " alpha
read -p "beta: "  beta
read -p "gamma: " gamma

echo "retrieved:"
echo "\$alpha: $alpha"
echo "\$beta:  $beta"
echo "\$gamma: $gamma"

$ echo "a\nb\nc" | /tmp/x.sh
retrieved:
$alpha: a
$beta:  b
$gamma: c
```

or, more intuitive to me:

```
$ (echo "a"; echo "multiple words"; echo optional quotes) | /tmp/x.sh
retrieved:
$alpha: a
$beta:  multiple words
$gamma: optional quotes
```

And, as '@Jean-Loup Sabatier' mentioned. `expect` is good to add logic if your input needs to change based on some logic, but that's a different question.